# ASPX C# Code Security

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I wire a web site using aspx and c#,  and I want to encript my c# code ( .cs files) No boby see and change my code.

Ho can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ASP.NET you have the option of Publishing your web site, which will produce .aspx "placeholders" and will compile the code into binary .dlls. However you must make sure that you do not have the option "**Allow this precompiled site to be updatable**" checked, so that no code or markup is visible on the hosting server.

Answer (score 1):

compile and publish your web site. and you can try dotfuscator

Comment: how can I compile my web site ?

Comment: on project explorer, select your project, click the right button, and you will see an option menu box. and there is an option what name is "publish" just click it and follow the instructions

Answer (score 1):

You should "Publish" your site which will compile all the files into .dll files:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Encrypting  (or even obfuscating) your code is probably the wrong way to go about it.

Instead, ensure only authorised persons have access to that machine. People accessing the site through IIS won't be able to access any .cs files.

Even if you compile your application, all .NET Assemblies can still be disassembled. Obfuscation makes it more difficult, but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebDeploy, which will make all the cs files into DLL

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=cfa66d50-90ce-49cb-b021-fefbd7a302ab